# Iterating a JSON array in LogicApps

Tags: azure-logic-apps

I'm using a LogicApp triggered by an HTTP call. The call posts a JSON message which is a single row array. I simply want to extract the single JSON object out of the array so that I can parse it but have spent several hours googling and trying various options to no avail. Here's an example of the array:

[{
"id": "866ef906-5bd8-44d8-af34-0c6906d2dfd7",
"subject": "Engagement-866ef906-5bd8-44d8-af34-0c6906d2dfd7",
"data": {
"$meta": {
"traceparent": "00-dccfde4923181d4196f870385d99cb84-52b8333f100b844c-00"
},
"timestamp": "2021-10-19T17:01:06.334Z",
"correlationId": "866ef906-5bd8-44d8-af34-0c6906d2dfd7",
"fileName": "show.xlsx"
},
"eventType": "File.Uploaded",
"eventTime": "2021-10-19T17:01:07.111Z",
"metadataVersion": "1",
"dataVersion": "1"
}]

Examples of what hasn't worked:
Parse JSON on the array, error: InvalidTemplate when specifiying an array as the schema
For each directly against the http output, error: No dependent actions succeeded.

Any suggestions would be gratefully received.

Answer (score 0):

You have to paste the example that you have provided to 'Use sample payload to generate schema' in the `Parse JSON` Connector and then you will be able to retrieve each individual object from the sample payload.

[image]

---

[image]

Comment: This works fine for an object but doesn't work here as the payload is an array

Comment: @TL1 Can you help me with what error message are you receiving? Because I could able to pull the data from HTTP through the `compose` connector

Answer (score 0):

You can extract a single JSON object from your array by using its index in square brackets. E.g., in the example below you'd need to use `triggerBody()?[0]` instead of `triggerBody()`. 0 is an index of the first element in the array, 1 - of the second, and so on.

[image]

Result:

[image]